# Show that if $n$ is odd, then $\frac {RP^n}{RP^{n-2}} \simeq S^n \vee S^{n-1} $

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces, projective-space

$\mathbf {The \ Problem \ is}:$ Show that if n is odd, then $X =\frac {RP^n}{RP^{n-2}}$$\simeq S^n \vee S^{n-1} =Y.$

$\mathbf {My \ approach}:$ We know
$RP^n =\frac {S^n}{C_2},$ then is it true that $ \frac {\frac {S^n}{C_2}}{\frac {S^{n-2}}{C_2}} \cong \frac {S^n}{S^{n-2}}$  ?

If it is true, then as $S^{n-2}$ is a contractible subcomplex of $S^n,$ then by this image(pg 14, Hatcher's book) ; we are done .

[image]

A small hint is warmly appreciated , thanks in advance .

Comment: Hint: consider a CW structure on $RP^n$.

Comment: Yes, we are collapsing all the cells in degree $\leq n-2$ , then we have remaining $1 \text {(n-1)-cell}$ and $1 \text  {n-cell}$ ,but then how to proceed ?

Comment: The relation over which you factor the smaller sphere is exactly the restriction of the relation on the bigger one. So you can indeed first take $S^n/S^{n-2}.$ However, you forgot to factor by $C_2$ after that.

Comment: You want your solution to use that $n$ is odd, because for even $n$ this is false, as witnessed by $H^n$.

Comment: Can you please write an answer regarding factoring of spheres? It would be very much helpful then .

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204568/mathbfrpn-mathbfrpn-2-simeq-sn-vee-sn-1-iff-n-is-odd/3204605#3204605